# How to pass a single form value with Ajax to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I´m trying to pass a value from an Ajax function to my PHP(in the same page) but can´t manage to catch it. I show the value with an alert and it seems to work properly, but the PHP never receives it. 
The php is working properly with a submit, but I want to use Ajax so that there is no need for page refreshing.

AJAX

```
$(function(){
        $('#ucli').on('input', function() {
            var client = $('input[name="ucli"]').val();
            var dataString = "ucli=" + client;
            alert(dataString);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data:  dataString,

                success: function(response){
                    $('ucli').html(data);


                }
            });  

        });
    });
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['ucli'])){

    $em = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['ucli'] . '');
    //SQL STUFF
}
```

Comment: Your `$.ajax` doesn;t have `url`, that's missing

Comment: @MilanChheda I´ve read that if you dont put it, the default option is your same page. Is this wrong?

Comment: Hmm, you are right @JuanjoC, my miss.

Comment: `$('ucli')` is wrong, it should be `$('#ucli')` or `$('.ucli')` depending on whether it's an ID or a class.

Comment: What's the point of `. ''` in your `mysqli_real_escape_string()` call? I see people doing this all the time, I've never gotten an explanation of why.

Comment: How do you know the PHP isn't receiving the parameter? Your code should work fine as long as there are no special characters in `client`.

Comment: @Barmar To answer your first question, I do it so that if the input is blank I won´t get an error. And I know the PHP isn´t receiving a parameter because I have both an alert and a table that depend on it, and do nothing after the Ajax alert.

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP to see what value it's getting.

Comment: Why would you get an error from a blank input if you don't use `.''`? Empty strings don't cause errors. And concatenating an empty string to an empty string just results in another empty string.

Comment: @Barmar It gets blank until the page is refreshed via some other functions that I have with windows.location.href. But until that nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#ucli').on('input', function() {
        var client = $('input[name="ucli"]').val();
        var dataString = "ucli=" + client;
        alert(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data:  {ucli: client},
            success: function(response){
                $('ucli').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the correct solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve quality of your post. Remember that you're answering for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons behind your code suggestion.

Comment: Can´t manage to make it work still... and I think their might be a small mistake(?). In the data:, shouldnt it be dataString instead of client? Ty for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function(){
    $('#ucli').on('input', function() {
    var client = $('input[name="ucli"]').val();
    var dataString = "ucli=" + client;
    alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({
    url: "path to php file",
    type: "POST",
    data:  dataString,

    success: function(response){
    $('ucli').html(data);


    }
    });  

    });
    });
```

Comment: Please explain what you've done, this looks identical. At the very least, format your code.

Comment: I have added a URL parameter to AJAX call. Thanks.

Comment: Haha yes I know. But add it to your post, explain what you've done instead of making someone puzzle. In this small snippet it's doable, but in larger or more complex answers, that no longer works

Comment: The URL defaults to the current page, and he says that the AJAX code is in the same script.

Comment: can't you separate the PHP file?

Comment: @user1544541 even in a separated file it won´t work. Already tried.

Comment: change data:  dataString, to data:{ 'ucli' :client}, and then try again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using GET method, which means you read the post payload from php://input , like that:

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: Another option you can pass data to url like : yoururl?ucli=encodeURI(theValue)

Comment: How would this be implemented?

Comment: The second option is just to use the url parameter in the $.ajax for your javascript code like 'url?ucli'+encodeURI(theValue), your current php code should work, but you should use this in php $_GET['ucli']

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: Yeah but I still couldnt make it work as I wanted too. Just ended up altering my code and doing something different at the end since I had to have it finished by todays morning.

Comment: You way it seems to me like you want to post a form of data, try $.ajaxForm instead of $.ajax, with along of your data as from string like : ucli=value&name2=value2, then you can get posted data from as :

$ucli = $_POST['ucli'];

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code ( when sending to the same page ) needs careful attention in order that the entire page contents are not returned in the response data. To that end I tend to use the following approach - `ob_clean` is useful in that it will clear the output buffers of any html that is generated to that point in the document

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['ucli'] ) ){
        /* 

            Prevent other page content prior to this point 
            being included in whatever response is sent by
            clearing the output buffer
        */
        ob_clean();

        /* Capture post variable */
        $ucli = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'ucli', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

        /* Do stuff */

        /* send response */
        echo $ucli;

        /* 
        Immediately terminate from this portion of code so that 
        the only response sent is what you determine above
        */
        exit();
    }

?>
```

The ajax function needs a url - as you are attempting to send a POST request to the same page you can use `location.href`. The callback (success) function should process the response whereas before it looked like it was processing the data that was sent.

```
$( function(){
    $('#ucli').on('input', function() {

        var client = $('input[name="ucli"]').val();
        var dataString = 'ucli=' + client;

        $.ajax({
            url: location.href,
            type: 'POST',
            data:  dataString,
            success: function( response ){
                $('ucli').html( response );
            },
            error: function( err ){
                alert( err )
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Full page example

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
        <title>jQuery</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
            $( function(){
                $('#ucli').on('input', function() {

                    var client = $('input[name="ucli"]').val();
                    var dataString = 'ucli=' + client;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: location.href,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data:  dataString,
                        success: function( response ){
                            $('#result').html( response );
                        },
                        error: function( err ){
                            alert( err )
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['ucli'] ) ){
                /* 

                    Prevent other page content prior to this point 
                    being included in whatever response is sent by
                    clearing the output buffer
                */
                ob_clean();

                /* Capture post variable */
                $ucli = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'ucli', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

                /* Do stuff */

                /* send response */
                echo $ucli;

                /* 
                Immediately terminate from this portion of code so that 
                the only response sent is what you determine above
                */
                exit();
            }

        ?>

        <form name='jqt' method='post'>
            ucli:<input type='text' name='ucli' id='ucli' />
            <div id='result'></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I still have the same issue, can´t capture the Post unless the page gets refreshed.. But ty for your answer.

Comment: There was a slight typo before ( extra `]` ) but it seems to work in test

Comment: I´m not using the ob_clean() since its messing up with a dynamic table I generate in the php. Could that be a mayor issue? The rest of the code is almost identical to your answer.

Comment: If the PHP code is before any html content is generated then you can probably remove `ob_clean` with no ill effect - so long as that code block terminates with `die` or `exit`